# Retrieving multiple set-cookies in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, cookies, httpwebresponse

I have a common function to retrieve the cookies (login):

```
postReq.CookieContainer = tempCookies

tempCookies.Add(postresponse.Cookies)

Return tempCookies
```

The site I'm getting the cookies from is giving me three `Set-Cookie`s:

```
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz; path=/
Set-Cookie: login=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz; expires=Sat, 10-Nov-2012 10:02:56
Set-Cookie: auth=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz; expires=Mon, 10-Nov-2014 10:02:56 GMT; path=/; domain=.domain.here
```

Though it successfully retrieves all three, when I try to pass the cookies, it only sends the first one:

```
Cookie: PHPSESSID=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz;
```

I want it to be like this:

```
Cookie: PHPSESSID=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz;login=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz;auth=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz;
```